# Why doesn't /dev/fb0 exist?

Tags: xorg, graphics, fbgrab

I am attempting to install and use [fbgrab](http://hem.bredband.net/gmogmo/fbgrab/), but it requires `/dev/fb0` to exist. How can I create this file?

My computer specs:
Dell Studio 1555, ATI Radeon 4500, proprietary graphics driver

Answer (score 2):

This may be down to X not using a framebuffer system, however the application you are trying to use is to take screenshots? Ubuntu already has a screnshot taking application, which you can launch from Applications > Accessories > Take Screenshot